# Adding values to variables by comparing two files in python

Tags: python

I have two text files.

```
File1:                       File2:  
X                            B    1    0.1
Y                            A    3    0.2
Z                            C    9    0.9 
A                            P    0    0.72 
                             X    2    0.32
                             Y    5    0.89
                             K    4    0.17
                             Z    7    0.59
```

I want to compare file1 and file2 and write to a new file the contents of file1 and associated numerical in columns 2 and 3 in file2.
The new file is:

```
X 2    0.32
Y 5    0.89
Z 7    0.59 
A 3    0.2
```

I used shell script to do it. But I prefer a python based script to integrate into my other part of code.
Any idea how to do it?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This may work:

```
path1 = 'path/to/file.txt'
path2 = 'path/to/file.txt'
path3 = 'path/to/file.txt'
file1_lines = []
with open(path1) as file1:
    for lines in file1:
        file1_lines.append(lines)

#remove \n
file1_lines = list(map(lambda s: s.strip(), file1_lines))

with open(path2) as file2:
    for lines in file2:
        if lines[0:1] in file1_lines:
            with open(path3, 'a') as file3:
                file3.write(lines)
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks.

Comment: Just a question. How to handle if file1 has repetitions and I intend to keep the order and repetitions intact in file3?  Thanks again